# SQL to display rows greater than or equal to a row value by keeping the same id and loop for all id's

Tags: mysql

I have 3 columns production number(int) , op number(int) and value(float). No column is distinct by itself. I need to look for the values <= 0 and display everything that's within that production number(int)

Example :

```
     PO#          |          OP#         |    values                           
     5247         |          100         |      12.0          
     5247         |          200         |      22.0   
     5247         |          300         |     -12.0  
     5247         |          400         |      52.0  
     6328         |          100         |      11.0  
     6328         |          300         |      55.0
```

I need to get these two rows

```
5247, 300 , -12.0 and 
5247, 400 , 52.0
```

not any other rows. How do I do that?

Comment: How you ended up with these rows? How is the title related to rest of the question?

Comment: Is this for mysql or sql-server. Those are two different RDBMS's

Comment: why you don't need to get first 2 rows? `5247 - 100 - 12.0 | 5247 - 200 - 22.0` they have same production number = `5247`?

Comment: once it finds a <=o row it has to display everything below that with respect to that id !!

Comment: mysql would help

Comment: So everything with a higher OP?

Comment: Tables do not have something below, after or anything like that. You have to defined the order yourself. Also tag only MySQL or SQL Server, unless you really are using both of them.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Alex : Even though they have same production number but their values >= 0 but in case of 5247 - 400 - 52.0 the value above it has a <= 0. it follows the order in op number 100 , 200 , 300 , 400 if 200 has a value <= 0 all other i.e 300,400 should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another guess to improve @DarshanMehta query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a3567/2

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM prodOps t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT po, op 
     FROM prodOps
     WHERE `values` < 0) f
ON t.OP >= f.op AND f.po=t.po
```

but what will happen if you have several records with negative values?
Check this fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/138f44/1

and *guess-solution* is:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM prodOps t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT po, MAX(op) op
     FROM prodOps
     WHERE `values` < 0 
GROUP BY po) f
ON t.OP >= f.op AND f.po=t.po
```

But I would suggest you to rethink the problem and redesign table and refactor your app. All this way goes to nowhere.

Comment: No problem, but think about refactoring please.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t
WHERE t.OP >= 
    (SELECT MAX(OP) 
     FROM table
     WHERE PO = t.PO AND value < 0);
```

**update**

Here's the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04657c/2/0).

Comment: Good try to guess. but OP did not ask for `t.OP >=` yet. and even if your guess is correct, your query will return last row `6328-300-55.0` as well, which I guess absolutely wrong.

Comment: Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: @sandeshbn Can you check the SQL fiddle attached? It returns the expected output. 
Alex, what makes you think it will return the last row?

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. i get this error !!

Comment: @sandeshbn I have replaced `OP` with `MAX(OP)` in sub query. Can you try now?

Answer (score 0):

using `exists()`

```
select *
from t
where exists (
  select 1
  from t as i
  where t.PO  = i.PO
    and t.OP >= i.OP
    and i.value < 0
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requiremetns

```
Select A.*
 From  YourTable A
 Join (
        Select [PO#]
              ,min([Values]) as minV
              ,max([Values]) as maxV
         From  YourTable
         Group by [PO#]
         Having min([Values])<0
      ) B
 on A.[PO#]=B.[PO#] and A.[Values] in (B.minV,B.maxV)
```

**Returns**

```
PO#     OP#    values
5247    300    -12
5247    400     52
```

Comment: thanks for the help. but i need to get all the other values too . i mean not only the max and min . because max value can be anywhere in the row .

Comment: @sandeshbn Notice that the data is grouped and joined on PO#, so you would get the pairs.  It is not just the total min/max values